# Calling same lambda function for each API resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, alias

I have an API that calls the same lambda function for each resource. Different actions are taken inside the lambda function based on what resource is accessed (taken from the resource field of the event object).

I am currently setting up multiple environments (development and production), using API stage variables to manage which function version is called as described [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-api-gateway-stage-variables-to-manage-lambda-functions/). However, I now have to add ":${stageVariables.lbfunc}" to each resource's lambda function field and manually give each of them the permission to actually use that alias of the lambda function. This seems like a big overhead, especially given that you cannot easily change the stageVariable to refer to a different alias, because you have to give permissions to each resource to use the new alias again.

Is there a way to set one function to use per API instead of setting the same for every endpoint, is my general approach wrong or is there simply no easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

U can create a proxy resource to direct all requests to one Lambda function. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-set-up-simple-proxy.html